# What is the name of the initialization used in char a[] = ""?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer, string-literals

What type of initialization is the following?

```cpp
char a[] = ""; // ???                 (copies array content)
char* q = a;   // copy-initialization (copies pointer)
// EDIT: originally it was `char q[] = a;` which doesn't compile
```

In C, it's called "array initialization".

In C++, it looks like copy-initialization, but I'm not sure. What is the exact paragraph in the standard where it's named?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes. I want to know how it named in c++.

Comment: @interjay sorry

Comment: I believe `char a[] = "";` is short hand for `char a[1] = {'\0'};` which would make it Aggregate Initialization.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Please do not change the original code. Otherwise it will confuse readers of the question and answers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The edit brought the question back to the original version which didn't include `q`. It is distracting from the real question and should be removed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it was a 'rush edit typo'. I meant `char* q = a;`

Comment: Related: *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not quite related, there was no follow-ups or divergence from main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the C++23 standard has to say about it:

###### 9.4.3 Character arrays [[dcl.init.string]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string)

1. An array of ordinary character type (6.8.2), `char8_t` array, `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array may be initialized by an ordinary string literal, UTF-8 string literal, UTF-16 string literal, UTF-32 string
   literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string-literal enclosed in braces (5.13.5).
   Additionally, an array of `char` or `unsigned char` may be initialized by a UTF-8 string literal, or by such a string literal enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the value of the string-literal initialize the elements
   of the array, with an integral conversion (7.3.9) if necessary for the source and destination value.

   [*Example* 1 :

   ```cpp
   char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
   ```

   shows a character array whose members are initialized with a string-literal. Note that because `\n` is a single character and because a trailing `\0` is appended, `sizeof(msg)` is 25. — *end example*]
2. There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements.

   [*Example* 2 :

   ```cpp
   char cv[4] = "asdf"; // error
   ```

   is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing `\0`. — *end example*]
3. If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized (9.4).

The standard doesn't mention the initialization from string literals more specifically than: *"string literals may initialize arrays of ..."* and the corresponding *CharT* which means it falls back to a plain **[aggregate initialization](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#:aggregate_initialization)**.

###### 9.4.2 Aggregates [[dcl.init.aggr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)

1. An aggregate is an **array** or a class (Clause 11) with ...

---

My conclusion is debatable and I find it hard to say with certainty that it is correct. It could also be that it should be seen as a plain *copy-initialization*.

###### 9.4.1. Initializers - General `[dcl.init.general]`

14. The initialization that occurs in the `=` form of a *brace-or-equal-initializer* or condition (8.5), as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (14.2), handling an exception (14.4), and **aggregate member initialization** other than by a *designated-initializer-clause* (9.4.2), is called **copy-initialization**.

Comment: Pretty sure it's still copy-initialization syntactically. The fact that there is initialization using a character array is just a specific form of that. The fact that it's initializing an aggregate is also just another detail.

Comment: I don't actually think this falls under the umbrella of aggregate initialization. [dcl.init.aggr] only describes what happens if list-initialization was used. The fact that the type is an aggregate type doesn't make it aggregate init, similar to how `T t;` is default-initialization even if `T` is an aggregate.

Comment: @JanSchultke Thanks for the edit! Yes, it could be seen as copy-init. `T array[N] = {other-sequence};` as that's shown at cppref. _"As part of **aggregate initialization**, to initialize each element for which an initializer is provided."_ - I'm not 100% sure which one is best.

Comment: That passage means that durring aggregate initialization, a bunch of sub-initializations can occur for the elements.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is not aggregate initialization, regardless of whether `= "..."`, `("...")`, `{"..."}` or `= {"..."}` is used. Each of these is just special cased in the (direct/copy)-(list-)initialization rules: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.3, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3.3 (That's how your quoted [dcl.init.string] becomes applicable in the first place.) On the other hand https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr has no rule that would be applicable.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm still unsure since both those paragraphs just refers to `[dcl.init.string]` without explicitly naming what the type of initialization is called. I would go for the most specialized name that fits, which I _think_ is aggregate init in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think there is any name for that kind of initialization. "_Aggregate initialization_" is supposed to mean a specific initialization procedure, not generally the initialization of an aggregate. In the standard it isn't explicitly defined, but when "_aggregate initialization_" is mentioned it is usually followed by a reference to [dcl.init.aggr] to indicate this specific procedure. As JanSchultke mentioned, it is for example possible to default-initialize an aggregate and then that is not meant to be _aggregate initialization_ (which doesn't call constructors).

Comment: Looks like there is no definitive answer can be provided by standard. How compilers name this construct in AST? _implementation defined name, oh yeah_

Comment: @user17732522 You may be correct and unfortunately it's way passed bedtime. I'll pick it up after work Tomorrow to see if I'll find something more to lean on either for or against aggregates :-) For now I added a possible copy-init disclaimer to the answer.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic I don't think a name is required. You just describe it syntactically? https://godbolt.org/z/z7hac71qY

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic It's indeed hard to find the precise name for it in the standard and I don't know much about compiler construction unfortunately. Perhaps they could call it _"initialization by string literal"_ and be done with it :-)

Answer (score -2):

Arrays do not have a copy constructor or the copy assignment operator. They are non-modifiable lvalues.

In the first declaration

```
char a[] = ""; // ??? (copies array content)
```

elements of the array `a` are intialized by elements of the string literal `""` that has array type `const char[1]`. It is an exception from the general rules adopted for initializing character arrays by string literals.

For the second declaraton

```
char q[] = a;  // copy-init (copies pointer)
```

the compiler will issue an error message by the reason pointed to in the beginning of the answer.

From the C++ 17 Standard (11.6.2 Character arrays)

> 1 An array of narrow character type (6.9.1), char16_t array, char32_t
> array, or wchar_t array can be initialized by a narrow string literal,
> char16_t string literal, char32_t string literal, or wide string
> literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal
> enclosed in braces (5.13.5). Successive characters of the value of the
> string literal initialize the elements of the array.  [ Example:

```
char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
```

> shows a character array whose members are initialized with a
> string-literal. Note that because ’\n’ is a single character and
> because a trailing ’\0’ is appended, sizeof(msg) is 25. — end example
> ]

Comment: This answer doesn't address what is being asked, which is what type of initialization `char a[] = "";` invokes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The question about using copy constructors.

Comment: The word constructor does not appear in the question, or in any of its revisions. It is asking what to call that initialization.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Reread one more the question and try to find words "Copy-initialization"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And by the way the question was changed. Initially there was declaration char q[] = a;  // copy-init (copies pointer)

Comment: The words "Copy-initialization" are quite easy to find. The question is asking if those words are the right ones to use to describe the code. I can assure you with high confidence that the question is not asking about copy constructors and it is not asking why `char q[] = a;` isn't working.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I added it as clarification to show syntax similarity to copy-initialization, but different behavior.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic And I answered your question about copy-initialization.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the question is in the title and never changed `What is the name of the initialization used in char a[] = ""`. Anyway I appreciate your effort (-1 is not from me).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry. It was actually edited. Original was `C++ what type of init is char a[] = ""` which have quite the same meaning